# Does Gravity Bow stack with Enlarge?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Does Gravity Bow stack with Enlarge?

As in I cast enlarge on myself, as a medium creatue, and the turn after I cast Gravity bow and on the third turn I shoot with my longbow. Does it do Huge dmg instead of large?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They don't stack, but possibly not for the reason you are expecting. Gravity Bow can only be used on a missile weapon. An Enlarged creature wielding a missile weapon does not actually deal any extra damage, as the missile reverts to normal size after firing. See text below -

> Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged creature's possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown and projectile weapons deal their normal damage.

If you really want an example that does stack, though, you could try [Lead Blades](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/leadBlades.html#_lead-blades-) and [Enlarge Person](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/enlargePerson.html#_enlarge-person). Lead Blades only works on melee weapons, though. And to go for gold, add in a dash of [Titan Mauler](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/classArchetypes/barbarian.html) - this would allow you to be wielding Large weapons in the first place, and so have them deal damage as if they were Gargantuan :)

Comment: Also, note that, while Enlarge Person doesn't work for this, the Psionic power Expansion, which works very similarly to Enlarge Person, does increase damage from projectile weapons (though still not from thrown).

Comment: Just to clarify, the titan mauler archetype doesn't allow you to wield large two-handed weapons, only two-handed weapons for your size in one hand. You can still wield large one-handed and large light weapons as normal.

Answer (score 1):

In D&D the question whether missle sizes existed at all in RAW was controversial. In pathfinder it's all still quite complicated as seen in this [forum discussion](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pyt2?Enlarge-and-Reduce-Person-when-considering-Bows), where it's argued that because [reduce person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person) actually reduces the damage (for projectile but not thrown weapons), the size of the launcher matters. For enlarge the wording is differently though!

**Reduce:** "Any reduced item that leaves the reduced creature's possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown weapons deal their normal damage (**projectiles** deal damage based on the **size of the weapon that fired them**)."

**Enlarge:** "Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged creature's possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown and projectile weapons deal their **normal damage**."

This is contradicting. However the gravity bow spell affects the arrow, not the launcher, thus if you assume that the weapon that fires the projectile matters for determining damage, then the damage should stack with a spell affecting the arrow additionally. If you feel like somehow only the size of the arrow matters, then you're out of luck. Well almost.

Carry large arrows around, drop them before you enlarge yourself, then pick it back up. Now you can use your magically large bow and mundanely large arrows with the gravity bow spell. - Or hire someone to do that for you, and waste their actions attaching the bigger quiver after the transformation. Maybe have a handed familiar do that?

It says "All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly [reduced or enlarged] by the spell." - Not exactly sure if that means if you pick up the large arrows they'd instantly become huge (thus giving you a -2 to hit penalty) and then shrink down to large again once you fire them... or if the size adjustment for equipment only happens when first affected by the spell for the duration of the spell, and anything you pick up after that stays small... Good question actually.

Comment: Wow, thx alot, ye I thought about this, and my character is a Bow maker, so I thought of making a large bow, but if the arrows is enough that be great. I'm gonna ask my GM, Thx!

Comment: I was working on making a large zen archer monk, and I struggled with the question of enlarge person and gravity bow. I never looked into reduce person, but you are correct, the spells contradict each other. I guess this becomes a DM. Ruling them as different spells and thus different effects isnt great because they do counter each other. So either the size change does affect the bow (reduce) or it doesnt (enlarge). Since items return to correct size when they leave, I feel enlarge is more accurate, and how I would rule as a DM.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get enlarge person and gravity bow to stack.
Now the common issue for enlarge person is that the missiles that leave you return to their normal size.
The mundane way of accomplishing this is either by having the correct arrow size on the ground and picking them up, or retrieving them from an extra-dimensional space where the arrow size was not affected by the spell.
The non-mundane or magical way is to use the  weapon property endless ammunition. Since it creates an appropriate sized missile to use regardless of current size for use after your size change, it doesnt change size when it leaves you.

I had thought abundant ammunition would work but it doesn't, so I cant find the spell I might have been thinking of.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/endless-ammunition