# What happens if an archer picks up ammunition after coming under the effects of Enlarge Person?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, equipment

Talking about creating an archer, and discussing how to get around a *Wind Wall* spell, me and another player were discussing *Enlarge Person* and how it might effect the arrows we were using.

We agreed that, whilst firing, the arrow would be Large-sized, and count as massive projectiles that would not be effected by *Wind Wall*, but that once fired and free of the bow and *Enlarge Person* effect, they would revert to medium size and therefore be effected as normal.

My question is this: *What would happen in the situation where the archer keeps a store of Large arrows on-hand, say strapped to their mount or whatever (but not on their own person), for use when Enlarged and attempting to shoot through a* Wind Wall *effect?*

My understanding, presuming that the archer *can* fire arrows from a bow that is a different size than the arrows are (which after discussion appears to be pending a further question), is that the arrows enlarge to Huge when picked up, and therefore apply oversized accuracy penalties when used, and then return to Large size once released, effectively bypassing the *Wind Wall*.

Comment: What do you mean by the inclusion of the rules-as-written tag on this question?  It sounds like  you *aren't* adjudicating from a rules first perspective, but rather from a group consensus perspective, is that right?  If you really are looking for a RAW analysis, feel free to rollback my edit and maybe add some info to that effect.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer is correct. The spell *enlarge person* says, "Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged creature’s possession (**including a projectile** or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size" (emphasis mine). However, you can ask the site to evaluate your house rule (once in it's in its you-think-it's-finished form) for your house rule's impact on the game.

Comment: (Also, lurking at the edges of this question is *another* question about whether ammunition must be the same size as the weapon that's to fire the ammunition. If, instead, *that* is your question — *Can only Large arrows be fired from a Large bow?* or whatever — I recommend posing a new question.)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer In all honesty, I wasn't aware there were house rules being involved here. I included the tag because it's a rules question, and therefore wanted to indicate that, and I was hoping for a "this is not dependent on your DM" answer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Both of your points I thought, following the discussion and generally the rules knowledge of the other player, were RAW anyway. The question is definitely the first bulleted point, and then I indulge my habit of musing on the question and posing potential answers as follow-ups.

Comment: It's okay. *Future Tip:* The rules-as-written tag is not a synonym for *just* the rules. The rules-as-written tag is for ultrastrict superlegalist readings of the text regardless of petty concerns like common sense or playability. There's no tag for *just* the rules because that's, like, *every* question.

Comment: So this isn't really an *enlarge person* question anymore but a *Can I shoot Colossal arrows from my Fine bow?* question? Or even a *Are there Colossal arrows?* question? Is that accurate?

Comment: ... that's a very helpful tip, and one I will take into account.

Comment: Ugh, I managed to misread my own question. The question _before_ the bullet point. I will edit the post to make it less ambiguous what I'm asking.

Comment: I've voted to put this question on hold as *Unclear what you're asking* because I think the question's muddled by the now-irrelevant inclusion of the spell *enlarge person.* If the spell *enlarge person* remains a factor in this question, could you edit the question to clarify how it is a factor? And, if it isn't a factor, could you edit the question to sharpen its focus on firing oversized or undersized projectiles from too-little or too-big projectile weapons?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I, after reading through this and thinking more about the nature of the question, have arrived at the same conclusion you did above, where the question actually does not pertain to _Enlarge Person_ at all. As such, after some time, I will delete the post and ask the question anew with more clarity. 
Would you recommend a tag of RAW for that question, as that is what I'd be looking to obtain?

Comment: related: [Reduce/enlarge person's equipment acquired while enlarged?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36741)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the rules-as-written tag for such a question precisely because the rules are unclear, speaking only in whispers. Personally, I try to reserve the rules-as-written tag for questions about A) things that are absurd based on the text to make sure I'm reading it right, and B) things that seem to have inter- or intratextual *contradictions* that I want resolved. You, however, can apply your own standards, of course. That is, it sounds like you want an answer that lets you *play the game* not an answer that'll hold up in Gamer Court.

Comment: (Also, you're going to have to edit this question or leave it on hold. Deleting it isn't an option after, I think, answers have been voted on.)

Comment: Much to learn about the correct use of the site, it would appear.
I'll apply an edit to the question that makes it more about clarifying the effect of _Enlarge Person_ on ammunition, and not about the vagaries of oversized ammunition.

Comment: Can you explain how this question differs from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36741/8610)?

Comment: At this point, I imagine it is simply a repeat question, that asks about a more specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit to clarify context: an earlier version of this question considered the possibility that a character might be able to use naturally-Large arrows without them changing size, by keeping them nearby but not on one's person, so as to have a naturally-Medium-temporarily-Large bow firing always-Large arrows that stay Large after being fired.]

"All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly enlarged by [Enlarge Person]."

You can't shoot an arrow without nocking it first, and you can't nock it without holding - i.e. carrying - it. So the Large arrow becomes Huge, and incompatible with the bow.

(Yes, arrows do have a size attribute; note the listing of two arrow sizes in table 6.4, and the item description: "An arrow used as a melee weapon... deals damage as a dagger of its size".)

Interpreting it the other way [i.e. the arrow doesn't change size] would have weird implications:

- Per the spell description, a throwing weapon enlarges in my possession and then shrinks when I let go of it, but this arrow does not. This seems weird.
- An arrow can also be an improvised melee weapon. If I (enlarged) pick up an arrow with the intention of stabbing somebody with it, presumably it enlarges just like any melee weapon would. Does it behave differently if I intend to shoot it at somebody? What if I change my mind?

[response to later version of question]

I agree with your understanding: *if* firing Huge arrows from a Large bow is permitted at all, the arrows enlarge to Huge and then drop back to Large when fired. Oversized accuracy penalties would seem appropriate, at the very least.

Comment: Can this answer cite a source that says a projectile weapon can only use ammunition of the same size as the weapon? (I know that common sense dictates that's true, but I'm unaware of the game ever making a distinction.) There *are* a couple of misunderstandings within this answer that should probably be corrected. (Take a look at the question's comments.) Please clarify if this answer is your reading of the rules or your house rules. (I won't downvote until you do; that downvote's not mine.)

Comment: Arrows implicitly have a size attribute: per p. 145, "an arrow used as a melee weapon... deals damage as a dagger of its size". I'm not aware of a reference that explicitly states arrows have to be the same size as the bow, but since the OP took this as read it didn't occur to me to second-guess that. (Especially since, as you say, it's common sense, and there's no rules-as-written tag on the question.) Beyond that, could you clarify what the misunderstandings are that you're referring to? I've read your comments but I'm still not seeing it.

Comment: That's totally fair, and that quotation should be mentioned in your answer. However, "It makes zero sense that a throwing weapon enlarges in my possession and then shrinks when I let go of it, but an arrow does not" seems to (*ahem*) miss the point about projectiles that's specifically mentioned by the *enlarge person* spell; the game says how that works already. No need to guess.

Comment: I think you have me, and perhaps the OP, backwards there? The OP was specifically asking if the usual ammunition-enlarges-then-shrinks-when-fired behaviour could be *avoided* (apparently by storing them off-person): "They remain Large". My point was that *given the way Enlarge Person normally affects weapons*, this exception would make no sense. You seem to have read that as "the way Enlarge Person normally affects weapons makes no sense" but that's *not* what I said.

Comment: Sincerely, I apologize for misunderstanding. I *do* think the answer would still benefit from including a bit more information from the question so the answer's context is clear and so that it's more easily grokked with a casual reading. Sorry if I ruffled any feathers.

Comment: Having updated the question, I feel like I should take the time to ask you if this means you need to update your answer, so that people can review their votes and potentially make amendments.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Cheers, we're good :-) I've edited to clarify context.

Answer (score 6):

### An *enlarged* Medium archer can use normally Large arrows picked up after [*enlarge person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) was cast; these arrows won't become Huge arrows

This question was discussed previously in [Reduce/enlarge person's equipment acquired while enlarged?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36741/reduce-enlarge-persons-equipment-acquired-while-enlarged) and that answer stands. So this chain of events does allow the Medium archer to fire Large arrows from a Large bow, dealing increased damage appropriately.

#### …But even the biggest arrows probably won't penetrate a [*wind wall*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wind-wall/)

The exception you're trying to use is *wind wall* saying that the spell's effect can't stop "a giant-thrown boulder, a siege engine projectile, and other massive ranged weapons."  It's ultimately up to your DM whether a Large arrow is similar enough to a boulder thrown by a giant or siege engine projectile, but I think most DMs would say no.

For comparison, an arrow weighs 0.15 lbs. (20 are 3 lbs.), but [the lightest ballista bolt weighs 10 lbs.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/siege-engines/) [As weight typically doubles per size category](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/armsAndArmor), a Colossal arrow weighs only 2.4 lbs., much lighter than even the lightest siege engine projectile!